# TSQL Error Statement 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why do i keep getting this error -- any suggestions?

> String Or binary data would be truncated

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you try to insert a longer string than a column will allow.

```
CREATE TABLE t (txt varchar(2))
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('asdf')
```